# How can I can solution to BCS gap eq. around critical point $T_c$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, phase-transition, superconductivity, approximations

The BCS gap equation is $$1=gn\int_0^{\Delta\epsilon} d\epsilon \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+\Delta^2}}\tanh\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+\Delta^2}}{2kT}.$$ At the critical point, we have $\Delta=0$, therefore we can calculate $T_c$. Now I want to investigate the relation $$\frac{\Delta(T)}{\Delta(0)}=1.73(1-\frac{T}{T_c})^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$ But I can't find a good approxiamation to reach the answer. I also didn't find a solution on the net. Does anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denotations are different but the keypoints seem clear. Let
$$\frac{1}{V_0\rho_F}=\int_{0}^{\omega_D}d\epsilon\frac{\tanh(\lambda(\epsilon)/2T)}{\lambda(\zeta)},\quad \lambda(\epsilon)=\sqrt{\Delta(T)^2+\epsilon^2}.$$
Let $T=T_c-\Delta T$ and we expand near $T_c$ w.r.t. $\Delta T$ and $\Delta$,
$$1\approx V_0\rho_F\int_{0}^{\omega_D}d\xi\frac{\tanh(\xi/2T)}{\xi}+\frac{V_0\rho_F\Delta T}{2T_c^2}\int_{0}^{\omega_D}\frac{d\xi}{\cosh^2(\xi/2T_c)}+\\+\frac{V_0\rho_F\Delta^2}{4T_c}\int_{0}^{\omega_D}\frac{d\xi}{\xi^2}\left(\frac{1}{\cosh^2(\xi/2T_c)}-\frac{2T_c\tanh(\xi/2T_c)}{\xi}\right).$$
Let $\kappa=\zeta/2T_c$ and then notice that $\omega_D/T_c\rightarrow\infty$, so
$$0\approx\frac{V_0\rho_F\Delta T}{T_c}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d\kappa}{\cosh^2\kappa}+\frac{V_0\rho_F\Delta^2}{8T_c^3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d\kappa}{\kappa^2}\left(\frac{1}{\cosh^2\kappa}-\frac{\tanh\kappa}{\kappa}\right).$$
The last integral is
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d\kappa}{\kappa^2}\left(\frac{1}{\cosh^2\kappa}-\frac{\tanh\kappa}{\kappa}\right)=-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}.$$
Finally, we find
$$-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}\frac{V_0\rho_F\Delta^2}{8T_c^3}=\frac{V_0\rho_F\Delta T}{T_c}\rightarrow\boxed{\Delta^2=\frac{8\pi^2}{7\zeta(3)}T_c^2(T-T_c).}$$
For $\Delta(T=0)$ is known that
$$\frac{\Delta(0)}{T_c}=\pi e^{-\gamma_E},$$
where $\gamma_E\approx 0.57$ is Euler-Mascheroni constant. For $\Delta(T)$ near $T_c$ we write
$$\Delta(T)=\left\{\frac{8\pi^2}{7\zeta(3)}\right\}^{1/2}T_c\sqrt{T-T_c}.$$
Dividing this expression by the expression for $\Delta(T=0)$, we find
$$\frac{\Delta(T)}{\Delta(0)}=\left\{\frac{8}{7\zeta(3)}\right\}^{1/2}\frac{e^{\gamma_E}T_c}{T_c}\left(1-\frac{T}{T_c}\right)^{1/2},$$
$$\frac{\Delta(T)}{\Delta(0)}\approx 1.737\left(1-\frac{T}{T_c}\right)^{1/2}$$

**Appendix: computation of integral**

To evaluate the integral, we use Weirstrass factorization theorem,
$$\cosh(x)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1+\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2(2n+1)^2}\right),$$
and then take twice logarithmic derivative, $\partial_x(\ln(\cdot))$, $\partial_x^2(\ln(\cdot))$, which gives
$$\frac{\tanh x}{x}=8\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2\pi^2+4x^2},\quad \frac{1}{\cosh^2x}=\sum_{n>0}\frac{8[(2n+1)^2\pi^2-4x^2]}{[(2n+1)^2\pi^2+4x^2]^2}.$$
Considering all the above, we obtain
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d\kappa}{\kappa^2}\left(\frac{1}{\cosh^2\kappa}-\frac{\tanh\kappa}{\kappa}\right)=-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{8}{\pi^2(2n+1)^3}=\\=-\frac{8}{\pi^2}\left(\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{8}\zeta(3)\right)=-\frac{7\zeta(3)}{\pi^2}.$$

**Appendix: relation between gap at $T=0$ and $T_c$**

From gap equation, we see that with $T\rightarrow 0$, the gap $\Delta\rightarrow\Delta(T=0)\equiv \Delta_0$, so
$$1=V_0\rho_F\int_{0}^{\omega_D}\frac{d\epsilon}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+\Delta_0^2}}.$$
Performing integration, we find
$$\frac{1}{V_0\rho_F}=\mathrm{arcsech}\,\left(\frac{\omega_D}{\Delta_0}\right)\rightarrow \boxed{\Delta_0=2\omega_D\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{V_0\rho_F}\right\}}.$$
Now let $T\rightarrow T_c$, so $\Delta\rightarrow 0$, then
$$1=V_0\rho_F\int_{0}^{\omega_D}\frac{d\epsilon}{\epsilon}\tanh\left\{\frac{\beta_c\epsilon}{2}\right\},$$
$$1=V_0\rho_F\int_{0}^{\beta_c\omega_D/2}\frac{dx\,\tanh x}{x}.$$
Integrating by parts, we obtain
$$\int_{0}^{\beta_c\omega_D/2}\frac{dx\,\tanh x}{x}=\left.\tanh x\ln x\right|_{0}^{\beta_c\omega_D/2}-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx\,\ln x}{\cosh^2x},$$
where in the last integral we assumed $\beta_c\omega_D/2\sim\infty$. The answer for this integral is
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx\,\ln x}{\cosh^2x}=-\gamma_E+\ln\frac{\pi}{4}$$
and this can be verified by differentiation w.r.t parmeter. So, we have
$$\int_{0}^{\beta_c\omega_D/2}\frac{dx\,\tanh x}{x}=\ln\frac{\beta_c\omega}{2}-\ln\frac{\pi}{4e^{\gamma_E}}=\ln\frac{2e^{\gamma_E}\omega_D}{\pi T_c},$$
which gives us
$$\boxed{T_c=\frac{2e^{\gamma_E}\omega_D}{\pi}\exp\left\{-\frac{1}{V_0\rho_F}\right\}.}$$
Comparing expression for $\Delta_0$ and $T_c$, we find that
$$\boxed{\frac{\Delta_0}{T_c}=\pi e^{-\gamma_E}\approx 1.76.}$$

**References:**

1. A. Altland & B. Simons, "Condensed Matter Field Theory", Ch. 7, problems for ch. 7

Comment: Thank you so much, bro!